# failed to run bin/schematool -dbType derby -initSchema

Tags: configuration, hive, derby

I have installed hive and derby and configure but its not running, I'm following the  official "[Getting Started](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-RunningHive)" guide on Apache website
It's not generating metastore.
I'm stuck here

```
[hadoop@Web hive]$ bin/schematool  -dbType derby -initSchema
which: no hbase in (/opt/hive/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/hadoop/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_101/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_101/jre/bin:/opt/hadoop/sbin:/opt/hadoop/bin:/opt/derby/bin)
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Metastore connection URL:    jdbc:derby:metastore_db;create=true
Metastore Connection Driver :    org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
Metastore connection User:   APP
Fri Nov 18 11:07:49 IST 2016 Thread[main,5,main] java.io.FileNotFoundException: derby.log (Permission denied)
Fri Nov 18 11:07:49 IST 2016 Thread[main,5,main] Cleanup action starting
ERROR XBM0H: Directory /opt/hive/metastore_db cannot be created.
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.StorageFactoryService$10.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.StorageFactoryService.createServiceRoot(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.createPersistentService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.createPersistentService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.createDatabase(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver20.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaHelper.getConnectionToMetastore(HiveSchemaHelper.java:73)
at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.getConnectionToMetastore(HiveSchemaTool.java:120)
at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.testConnectionToMetastore(HiveSchemaTool.java:174)
at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.doInit(HiveSchemaTool.java:278)
at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.doInit(HiveSchemaTool.java:264)
at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.main(HiveSchemaTool.java:505)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Cleanup action completed
ERROR XBM0H: Directory /opt/hive/metastore_db cannot be created.
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.StorageFactoryService$10.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.StorageFactoryService.createServiceRoot(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.createPersistentService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.createPersistentService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.createDatabase(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver20.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaHelper.getConnectionToMetastore(HiveSchemaHelper.java:73)
at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.getConnectionToMetastore(HiveSchemaTool.java:120)
at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.testConnectionToMetastore(HiveSchemaTool.java:174)
at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.doInit(HiveSchemaTool.java:278)
at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.doInit(HiveSchemaTool.java:264)
at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.main(HiveSchemaTool.java:505)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
============= end nested exception, level (3) ===========
Cleanup action completed
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Failed to get schema version.
Underlying cause: java.sql.SQLException : Failed to create database 'metastore_db', see the next exception for details.
SQL Error code: 40000
Use --verbose for detailed stacktrace.
*** schemaTool failed ***
```

hive configuration file - hive-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
<value>jdbc:derby:metastore_db;create=true</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
<value>org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: `Directory /opt/hive/metastore_db cannot be created.` Perhaps Derby is being run with a Java Security Manager policy in place which is preventing Derby from creating that directory? Or, check filesystem permissions on that filesystem?

Comment: Hive installation directory should be owned by hadoop user.